# Vim with ctags and omnicomplete not completing C struct fields

Tags: c, vim, ctags, omnicomplete

I have my vim setup to use omnicomplete with ctags and its all working well. I have set my .ctags to tag struct members and they are in the tag file but omnicomplete just shows

```
Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

when I do something like mystruct. or mystruct-> 
Everything else offers good completion.

Is there something else I need to enable in vim or omnicomplete or ctags?

Comment: Do you mean "omnicppcomplete" instead of "omnicomplete"? If no, then you might need to use omnicppcomplete ( http://goo.gl/lFqXr ). Also, take a look at clang_complete for perfect completion of C/C++/Objective-C code ( http://goo.gl/v7wXQ )

Comment: Dmitry thanks for that I found the clang one to work perfectly, along with omnicomplete I have total code completion in vim for C. If you want to answer the question I will set answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean "*omnicppcomplete*" instead of "*omnicomplete*"? If no, then you might want to use [omnicppcomplete](http://goo.gl/lFqXr).

Also, take a look at [clang_complete](http://goo.gl/v7wXQ) for perfect completion of C/C++/Objective-C code.